# Implementing current html into WordPress navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a piece of code in html. I would like my menu i WordPress to be like this accordion.

**This is my html**

```
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <li>
        <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>Menu 1<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Menu 2<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In funtions.php I have the following code where I call the navigation function.

```
function bh_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => false,
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

I call the function with the following code

How do I make my navigation generate the html above?

Comment: Please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check updated code:

```
 wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">%3$s</ul>',
    'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu_add
));
```

Code for function.php

```
    class Walker_Nav_Menu_add extends Walker {
    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'submenu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;

        if($depth=='0'){
        $item_output .= '<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i><a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>';
        }
        else if($depth=='1'){
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        }    


        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 1, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }

} // Walker_Nav_Menu
```

Comment: Thanks, you are very close. 
Your code outputs this html: 

<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
 <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item-71"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <div class="link">
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item-56"><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item-51"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>

in your html the Menu 1 is in <li> but this should be inside <div class="link">Menu 1</div>

any idea how to fix this?